# Close editing of formula fields in PDF

Tags: pdf

I have a PDF with formula fields. Now I finished filling out the forms and would like to submit them. However I would like to make sure that nobody can edit my text. In other words, I would like to "close" the editing of the form fields. I tried printing with a PDF printer that prints to file, but this increased the file size and reduced the quality at the same time. What other options do I have? I am using Kubuntu 14.4.

Comment: @muru: I deleted the question on the other site.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution for this using the command line program `pdftk` and it's `flatten` option:

```
pdftk input.pdf output output.pdf flatten
```